# In a simple LDO regulator, is the op amp working in positive feedback?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ldo

Below they're connecting the feedback voltage FB to *positive* pin of op amp. Isn't this *positive* feedback ? Because, when the output voltage increases, the feedback voltage increases, which then increases the op amp output.

But my textbook claims that the output voltage is stable because of the heavy *negative* feedback. I'm not able to see negative feedback here. What am I missing  ?

[image]

Comment: It's a P-MOS transistor. The higher the gate voltage, the more it turns **off**. Increasing feedback -> increasing op-amp output -> decreasing current.

Comment: Yes - it is counter-intuitive to a normal feedback loop, because it is driving a *P-Channel* MOSFET. The higher the feedback voltage is away from the reference voltage (i.e. the higher the error), the higher you want to drive the P-FET.

Comment: Wow! so that PMOS is providing 180 degree phase shift to give negative feedback! I completely missed that! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @immibis maybe if you've time, if you post it as an answer I'd like to mark it as the best answer. There is no way I could have seen that sneaky PMOS and my textbook is terrible at explaining details. Thanks again!

Comment: Now that you have that part, build one and see if it oscillates.

Comment: @jonk I'm going to similate this, may I ask another question. How do they(companies like Texas Instruments etc) generate Vref for the op amp - pin ? Should I simply use the input voltage and a series resistor + zener diode ?

Comment: @rsadhvika a general zener is okay, but you can get diodes designed to be reference voltages (i.e. more accuracy, temperature compensated, etc.). Just google "1V voltage reference" or something, as an example.

Comment: If you are simulating it, you can build a band-gap reference out of transistors and resistors (non-trivial) or use the model for a TL431 (2.5V) or TLV431 (1.25V) reference chip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a P-MOS transistor. The higher the gate voltage, the more it turns **off**.

As the feedback voltage increases, the op-amp increases the gate voltage, which decreases the current.

Answer (score 3):

There is 180 phase shift across gate to drain.
So, for a PMOS: feedback should be connected to a + ve terminal
for a NMOS: feedback  should be connected to a - ve terminal